# ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs not being able to run

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably a really simple task, but for some reason my code doesnt run. This code has worked for the past few months but when I initiate the command now it doesnt work.

The code that I had used (without any change) is the following:

```
Sub Copy()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\[File Location]" & "File Name " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
End Sub
```

Wondering if anyone could provide any advice / tips on how to solve/troubleshoot >.< many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error message that occurs, if any?

Comment: Looks like maybe you are missing a backslash between the location and filename?

Comment: Hi @BigBen I've a backslash between the location and filename. Separately, there's no error message, just that nothing happens, which is quite strange. Plus I've coded something similar for my intern and his works just fine :/

Comment: Most likely the file isn't saving where you think it is. I suggest you `Debug.Print "C:\Users\[File Location]" & "File Name " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsm"` and carefully inspect the output in the Immediate Window

Comment: So `"File name "` is just a placeholder for what you actually have in your code? It would be helpful to see your actual code as-is.

Comment: Thanks @braX Sub Copy()

'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Desktop\TRD\" & "Corp Bond Run " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
End Sub'

Comment: `C:\Users\Desktop` looks off, normally there should be a user parent folder before `Desktop`.

Comment: Is the user name TRD?  Then it should be C:\Users\TRD\Desktop\

Comment: Many thanks for that @BigBen and braX.  I've added my user C:\Users\ayjs556\Desktop\TRD\Run\ but seems like its still unable to load; debug is showing me C:\Users\ayjs556\Desktop\TRD\Run\Corp Bond Run 10-Dec-2021.xlsm

Comment: To add: I've C:\Users\ayjs556\Desktop\TRD\Run\Corp Bond Run 10-Dec-2021.xlsm in my results, but when i change the code back to ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\ayjs556\Desktop\TRD\Run\" & "File Name " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52 and run the code, nothing happens/no action happens.

Comment: Are you really trying to get the words "File Name" as part of the filename? or is that supposed to be a variable?

Comment: @braX i made that a variable. Sorry quite new to this, never learnt coding in my life, modified off a fellow colleague's code (who has since left)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is broken up a little for you. The `Environ()` function just gets the user name of whoever is logged in when the code runs.

Replace how `File1` is created if you want something else. <sup>(you did not include that part in your question)</sup>

```
Sub SaveIt()
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim File1 As String
    Dim Filename As String

    SavePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\TRD\Run\"
    File1 = Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")(0) ' strip out the file extension
    Filename = File1 & " " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SavePath & Filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```

<sub>Note: This assumes the folder you are saving it to exists already.</sub>

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this, works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to help. Please remember to click the green checkmark to select the answer that helped you.